Divergent summation
Let $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ be a sequence such that $0<x_i<1\ \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \cup {0}$.Consider the following series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x_i}{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{i-1} x_k \right)^2}.$$
I want to find a series $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ that makes this series divergent or prove that there is no such a series. Do you guys have any idea?

Terminology advice: what you call "summation" is really called "series". TeX advice: use \sum instead of \Sigma. Finally, please use a high-level tag like "ca.classical-analysis-and-odes". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

You can take $x_i$ way bigger than all the previous $x_k$'s. Did you mean for the summation in the denominator to run up to $k=i$ instead of $k = i-1$?

@mathworker21 In both cases one can make the series divergent. If the sum in the denominator runs up to $k=i$, then the sequence $(1,-2,2,-2,\dotsc)$ produces a constant denominator $1$ and a divergent series.

@GHfromMO There's a chance it could be interesting if sum goes up to $k=i$ and if $x_i > 0$ for all $i$.

@mathworker21 Well, that should be asked in a new MO post.

Define $x_i$ recursively as follows. Let $x_0:=1$, and for $i\geq 1$ let
$$x_i:=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{i-1} x_k \right)^2.$$
Then each term in the series equals $1$, hence the series diverges.
